# Include the value of a system environment variable when setting title in vimrc

Tags: vimrc, environment-variables

I have the number of my xterm (i.e., the value of /dev/tty??) saved as an environment variable, TTY e.g., `echo $TTY` returns `11`.     I'd like to include this number in the title, along with the name of the file when I open vi.

Currently I have

```
set titlestring=%-25.55F\ %a%r%m titlelen=17
```

I've tried the obvious:

```
set titlestring=$TTY\ %-25.55F\ %a%r%m titlelen=17
```

But this doesn't expand $TTY, e.g., and the title of my xterm window is

```
$TTY myFilename
```

instead of

```
11 myFilename
```

Could somebody please advise how to get the desired result?     Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables are not expanded in the context of a `set` command. So use `let`:

```
let &titlestring = $TTY . ' %-25.55F %a%r%m'
set titlelen=17
```

Comment: But this will expand the value at the time of the definition of the value, not when displaying it. One also needs to be careful about expanding the value, if it can contain whitespaces I think (not sure about that)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt From the name "TTY", I would not expect it to change during runtime. As we use `let` here, no escaping of whitespaces is needed. Would be different with `exe "set titlestring=" . $TTY . "..."`

Comment: I see, thanks for clarification

Comment: Fabulous, thanks very much, @Ralf and @ChristianBrabandt.    One followup question:   most of the time I call vi with an alias that first sets the TTY variable.    But not always.    Is there a way to condition the titlestring line on the existence of $TTY?   That is, in csh, I'd write  `if ( ($?TTY) ) then let ...`?

Comment: @LeoSimon Then you'll need `if $TTY != '' | let &titlestr=... | else | let &titlestr=... | endif` (replace '|' with line breaks).

Comment: Thanks @Ralf, I modified your above string to just `let &titlestring = $TTY . '  ' . $fileID` but when i do this the `set titlelen` command on the following line doesn't have any effect.   So it must depend on something in the arcane  `' %-25.55F %a%r%m'`.      I tried a million perturbations of the arcanity, but nothing worked. 
  Could you advise how to get `titlelen`  to work for my stripped down version, please?

Answer (score 4):

For this particular case where `$TTY` is constant and not likely to change, [@Ralf's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25406/18609) of using `let &titlestring` to compose the setting string value is recommended.

Another possible approach is to use a `%{...}` group inside the setting value, which will evaluate it every time the setting is used.

In this case, this would work:

```
set titlestring=%{$TTY}\ %-25.55F\ %a%r%m titlelen=17
```

The `'statusline'` option also uses similar %-sequences and using a `%{...}` with a valid Vimscript expression is also an option there.